# Custom serializer JAVA -> JSON (JAXB)

Tags: java, json, serialization, jaxb, adapter

I need to serialize POJO in a specific way.  I'm using JAXB in this way:

```
public void convertToJson(TaskActionData input) {

try {
    JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(TaskActionData.class);
    Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
    marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
    marshaller.setProperty(MarshallerProperties.MEDIA_TYPE, "application/json");
    marshaller.setProperty(MarshallerProperties.JSON_INCLUDE_ROOT, false);

    marshaller.marshal(input, System.out);

} catch (JAXBException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Right now im converting this object to JSON in this form:

```
{
"name": "value",
"name": "value",
"name": 
   [    true,
    false,
      false,
      false,
      false,
      false,
      false,
      false,
      false
    ],
"name": {"name": 
[{
    "name": "value",
    "name": [{
        "name": "value",
        "name": "value",
        "name": "value"
    }],
    "name": [{
        "name": "value",
        "name": "value",
        "name": "value",
        "name": "value"
    }],
    "name": "value",
    "name":  [],
    "name": [{
        "name": "value",
        "name": "value",
        "name": "value"
    }]
}]
}}
```

And I need that each list is wrapped into "items" label, like that :

```
{
"name": "value",
"name": "value",
"name": {
    "name": [],
    "items": [
        true,
        false,
        false,
        false,
        false,
        false,
        false,
        false,
        false
    ]
},
"name": {"name": {"items": [{
    "name": "Tvalue",
    "name": {"items": [{
        "name": "value",
        "name": "Bvalue",
        "name": "value"
    }]},
    "name": {"items": [{
        "name": "Tvalue",
        "name": "value",
        "name": "value",
        "name": "value"
    }]},
    "name": "value",
    "name": {"items": []},
    "name": {"items": [{
        "name": "value",
        "name": "value",
        "name": "value"
    }]}
}]}}}
```

So there will be need to write custom serializer. I tried to find some solution but with no success

Comment: *So there will be need to write custom serializer. I tried to find some solution but with no success* - What solutions did you try? What issues are you having with your custom serializer?

Comment: Hmm I also didn't found any example. Maybe I will have to write it from scratch :(

Comment: I solved it with replace and regex :)

Answer (score 0):

```
I created something like that:

public String decorateJSON(String input){
    String output = input.replaceAll("\\[", "{\"items\":[");
    output = output.replaceAll("]", "]}");
    return output;
}

public String undecorateJSON(String input){
    String output = input.replace("{\"items\":", "");
    output = output.replaceAll("]}", "]");
    return output;
}
```

Will try if it works later :)

Comment: Ok, I can't use this solution, however there is possibility to use other framework than JAXB